# How ERC20 token set tax mount when buy/sell on Pancake Swap?

Tags: solidity, erc20

I created ERC20 (just basic with Openzepplin), I can add liquid to Pancake. Buy, what I need is:

- When users buy token on Pancake, I need to transfer 3% amount BNB  to Owner Address.
- When users sell token on Pancake, I need to transfer 3% amount Token  to Owner Address.

I've research and found that: in function _transfer, we can detect from/to is pancake pair address, then we know client is buying or selling. Buy I dont know how to transfer tax to another address (ex Owner address).

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can make the transfer function to payable and write your logic in to transfer the percentage.